# Is it possible to run 2xBlackberry Enterprise Servers off one external i.p

Tags: nat, blackberry, bes

We currently run blackberry professional (express?) to handle our small number of blackberry handsets with exchange.

I am currently studying for BCP-211 and BCP-213 exams and would like to load full BES trial on a virtual machine (along with its own srp key) and this will have internet access.

At present we only have the one external ip nat'd via a netgear dg834 router.

Will this cause problems with the production server which runs on the standard 3101 port.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, won't cause problems at all. Each server maintains its own TCP SRP connection with the Blackberry network.

Comment: thankyou should help me get to grips with some of the nitty gritty of the BES console i havent used yet :)